# Error with yarn run command, can not find a script name

Tags: node.js, npm, yarn-v2

I am using mac M! and I am trying to run the backend part of a project and here is the instruction in the readme file:

1. `yarn set version berry`
2. `yarn install`
3. Run `yarn run build_core` to build database repo. You'll need to do this after every change to it
4. copy .env files into `.config` folder and `.env` in each repo you run individually
5. run with `yarn run <service name>` (See root package.json for commands)
6. Install docker vs-code extension, right click the `docker-compose.yaml` files in `./docker-compose` and click "Compose Up"

I successfully installed yarn, but when I go to the 3rd step, here is the error:
[Click to see the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfIYn.png)

Anyone knows what is the issue and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What's in the `package.json -> scripts`  section?